# RxSwift repeated action

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm switching from RAC and want to have a repeated network request, returning different result types depending on the API of the request.

I want to use an interval, but I don't know how to match the return types.

```
var loop: Observable<Element> {
    return Observable<Int>.interval(5.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).map { _ in
        // Do network request and return Observable<Element>
    }
}
```

I need to invoke Observerable.interval with type Int - but return Observable. How would I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use flatMap:

```
var loop: Observable<Element> {
    return Observable<Int>.interval(5.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).flatMap { _ in
        return networkRequest() // returns Observable<Element>
    }
}
```

Comment: How to stop this timer ?

Comment: Store subscription in variable, and dispose it when not needed using `dispose()`.

Comment: `interval` deprecated, use `DispatchTimeInterval`